# Bootstrap button on navbar menu toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar" />
        <span class="icon-bar" />
        <span class="icon-bar" />
      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">QA</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu<span class="caret"/></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My question is the following:
Is it possible in Bootstrap to have the button from the navbar inside the 
toggle menu as a link and not as a button? 
Lets say the user goes from desktop to mobile resolution and he clicks the hamburger menu and the link 'Sign In' is displayed but not as a button anymore

[image]

Comment: share a little few code for more understand your issue please.

Comment: @darkomen The 2 parts above is the code used for the navbar

Comment: thank you for sharing but you must edit your post with your code for more readable. Not in a comment. And Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `hidden-xs` class to the button in your nav bar

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn hidden-xs">Sign in</button>
```

Add a menu item with class `visible-xs` somewhere in your menu

```
<li class="visible-xs"><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
```